# Using "regarding the" instead of "as to the"

Tags: phrase-choice

> We will also try to be as clear as possible **as to** the complicated and/or scientific information

Is this right? I have some doubts in the "as to the.." part, it just feels weird. Would it be "more correct" if I wrote this?

> We will also try to be as clear as possible **regarding** the complicated and/or scientific information

Comment: it is grammatically correct, but you would be using three as es, which is redundant. I would use any of these "regarding, concerning, with respect to,"

Comment: I may use ***'on'***, perhaps! Because to me it sounds better when we stay clear *on* something.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences have a similar meaning.

In your example, **as to** and **regarding** perform the same function to mean **with regards to**.

However the negative of both, **as** ***not*** **to** and **without regards to** has two different meanings:

> 1) We will explain things so **as not to** overcomplicate a complicated subject.
>   2) We will explain things **without regards to** overcomplicating a complicated subject.

#1 means the explanation will attempt to explain things simply
#2 does care how complicated the explaination might be